# How do I check to see if the same thread is executing in a Windows Universal Application?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am used to troubleshooting multi-threaded applications using System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread in C#.  Is it possible to access the thread ID in a Windows Universal App ?

Answer (score 0):

this should tell you everything you need to know about debugging multithreaded applications.

[msdn debugging multithreaded applications with visual studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164746.aspx)

theres a link on this page that allows you to name your threads so you may be able to access it by name if you need to once its been initiated.

Comment: I need to access the thread IDs in code.  I know how to view threads in Visual Studio.  Thanks.